# What is the use of Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK registry key?

Tags: java, windows

While I was doing multiple Oracle JDK installations (JDK 16.0.1 and JDK 17.0.8) for my Windows 10 pc, I came across Windows Registries like this :
[image]

What is the use of these registry entries and where are they used ?

Comment: By the installer, for a start, and by IDEs such as Netbeans.

Comment: @user207421 Could you please place it as an answer, I will then accept it.